# how to do an arithmetic update of a column in clickhouse?

Tags: sql, sql-update, clickhouse

I have a numeric column of data in a table which is off by 18000 because of a bug. All the data needs to have 18000 added to it. How is that done in clickhouse ?

ie I need something like this but dont know how to do it.

```
update table mytable set col1 = col1 + 18000;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alter table mytable update col1 = col1 + 18000 where 1;
```

And check system.mutations table after.

Alter is async, so you need to wait for the end of a mutation.

https://www.altinity.com/blog/2018/10/16/updates-in-clickhouse

Comment: Such an interesting syntax. That almost works but getting this error.DB::Exception: Cannot UPDATE key column `Slice`.  I guess I have to rebuild this table which is a few weeks of data. But i will accept this as the correct one.

Comment: CH does not allow to update KEY columns because it needs a table re-sort. Data (all rows all columns) is placed on the disk in the order agree with KEY. In my case for example such update will need to read 500TB / resort / write. It will take months and need 1PB disk space.

Comment: Yep I understand the problem Denis and your syntax is correct.  I dont have a lot data about 40 tables at 20 million rows each and trying to figure out how to rebuild this data without loosing it.